# How to tell if there is a spy on my head?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Without looking up, how can I tell if there is a spy on my head?

Comment: Is this a common occurrence?

Comment: It happens every now and then when you are an engineer.  Not so much when you are running about but you never know!

Comment: So, I don't play TF2 but I've got to ask... why would a spy be on your head?

Comment: Call for a pyro to check.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips If you're not moving around (e.g., an engie) and it's a quiet Spy, it's a great way to inform teammates of who's moving around near the engie nest in preparation of pushing forward an uber (It's obviously easier if you know who'll be there). Hiding on top of a dispenser or sentry has similar benefits.

Comment: Another reason a Spy might be on your head: Getting on top of an Engineer's head and crouching when he has his back pressed up to the wall, with some careful aim, is one of the only ways to successfully backstab him when he's in this position.

Comment: Spy on the head: https://gfycat.com/PessimisticOblongCicada

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try crouching or jumping. If you can't uncrouch or jump, well, there's a spy sitting on your head.

Note that if you crouch and you weren't crouching before, the spy will probably notice the change and run for it, so jumping might be best.